# Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR: while changing datatype to boolean from integer in laravel migration using PostgreSQL

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, migration

I'm trying to change column type from integer to boolean.

I've created a migration with following

```
$table->integer('has_varients')->default(0)->comment('1:yes, 0:no');
```

Now I'm creating another migration to alter datatype

```
$table->boolean('has_varients')->nullable()->change();
```

When running php artisan migrate, I'm getting following error,

```
SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  column "has_varients" cannot be cast automatically to type boolean
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING has_varients::boolean". (SQL: ALTER TABLE products ALTER has_varients TYPE BOOLEAN)
```

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: If column already contains data then, laravel has no idea how to convert it to boolean, as per my knowledge it wont be straight forward to change it like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to explicitly tell the SQL statement how to convert it.

Postgres itself wouldn't know what false or true should be represented in DECIMAL(12,4).